# Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting android 12 and higher etc etc

Tags: android

I know there are similar questions being asked already over here, with answers provided, however none of them seems to work for me, therefore i'm asking for help here since i am completely new to android studio usage and XML related syntax.

This whole issue started with my android studio having the issue of installed build tools corrupted for revision 31.0.0.

After reading a post over here about changing the d8.bat and d8.jar to dx.bat and dx.jar respectively, i followed the instructions and the build tools issue was solved. However, another issue occured which is this current one, about the manifest merger failed etc etc.

I read another post over here about adding the syntax `android:exported="true"` into the manifest file, which supposedly worked for others but still didnt work for me. [See here for after i added the code line. I'm a newbie when it comes to XML syntax so do correct me if i added it under the wrong area.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgCyA.png)

Can someone please help me with this issue? New to android development and android studio in general, only learnt java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you added exported in Application Tag whereas you have to add it to Activity Tag. Like this,

```
<activity
        android:name=".presentation.ui.activity.HomeActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also be careful here which activity you choose to make exported. Only set those Activities exported = true which you want to allow other Applications to open.
For example if your App has Settings Activity you don't want other Apps to open it Directly.

Comment: Also remove the exported= true from Application Tag.