# How to solve minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on a java app project in android studio. Everything working fine but 2-3days before I got some strange issues.  I searched a lot on `google` even on `stackOverFlow` but did not get any working solution.

I am using `compilesdk 30` and it gives me the following error.

```
The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-beta01.
```

I searched and changed the `compilesdk 30` to 31. After that, I got the following errors in the manifest file.

```
Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. DataFinderStudio.app main manifest (this file)

Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. DataFinderStudio.app main manifest (this file)
```

These are the two errors. One has been resolved when put `android:exported` in the intent filter but the second one is still there. I put everywhere exported but the result was the same.

Again I did the search and got the recent solution if I put the following code in dependency gradle then it will be solved.

```
def work_version = "2.6.0"
    // Force WorkManager 2.6.0 for transitive dependency
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version") {
        force = true
    }
```

I did the same but again the result in the same. I am totally fed up. tried each and every solution. Rebuild the project but nil. I saw some recent questions which are all same but my issue was not resolved so this is not a duplicate question. I tried everything.

Comment: Check out this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68789251/manifest-merger-failed-apps-targeting-android-12-and-higher-etc-etc/68789336#68789336

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal I have added exported in an activity tag but a same error that `Menifest merger fail' In actual if I remove the exported it shows two same errors `android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>' but when I added exported one goes out and one still there.

Comment: You have add it it in all the activities you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All folks who are getting these errors. I solved this error by adding following line of code in app-level build.gradle file under defaultconfig.

```
configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.6.0' }
        }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
        }
```

I have already pasted the `work-runtine` line of code but @soujanya gave me one more line of code which is `core-ktx:1.6.0`. I pasted same under `work-runtime` and **BOOOOM!!!** it suddenly compiled my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `minCompileSdk` to **31** change it to **21** in the app level `build.Gradle`

Comment: I have `minsdkversion 19` II changed it to 21 but bad luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in build.gradle under dependency

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
}
```

Comment: after adding this again same error `the minCompileSdk (31) specified`

Comment: This is totally meaningless answer, better delete it.

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal yep this solution did not do anything.

Comment: Try adding the same what i posted

Comment: I faced the same issue and tried everything. The above line solved my issue

Comment: @soujanya I did copy-paste same as like under dependency but no result :(

Comment: @soujanya after adding the following code of line under default config successfully launched application `configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.6.0' }
        }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
        }`

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal please look into it

Comment: @soujanya, he is getting error in Work Manager dependency and your answer is telling him to override core ktx library's version, which is meaningless.